# C : Function to read a file to a singly linked list and return head pointer?

Tags: c

Im writing a program that will populate a singly linked list and process data from a file containing football teams and results by storing them sequentially in node structures. The problem arises when trying to traverse and display the populated linked list.

I have tried

1.passing a head pointer as an argument

2. creating head node inside a function then returning it

3.(As in code i provided) Both.

None of it works. Created some test printf-s.

Structure:

```
   typedef struct node{
    char host[50];
    char* guest[50];
    int nrgh;
    int nrgg;
    struct node* next;
   }node;
```

Loader function:

```
   node* load_ll(node* head,char* file_name){
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
    node *curr;
    curr = head;
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Greska pri otvaranju fajla.");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buff[100];
    char* tok;

    while(fgets(&buff,100,fp) != NULL){

         curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            if(curr == NULL)
            {
            printf("Error creating a node.");
            exit(1);
            }

      tok = strtok(buff,",");
      strcpy(curr->host,tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL,",");
      strcpy(curr->guest,tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL,",");
      curr->nrgh = atoi(tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL,",");
      curr->nrgg = atoi(tok);

      curr->next = NULL;

      printf("%s\n",curr->host);
      printf("%s\n",curr->guest);
      printf("%d\n",curr->nrgh);
      printf("%d\n",curr->nrgg);
      curr=curr->next;

      return head;

    }
```

Traverse and display function:

```
void print_matches(node* head){
 node* curr = head; 

 while(curr->next != NULL){

   printf("%s\t%d\n%s\t%d\n",curr->host,curr->nrgh,curr->guest,curr->nrgg);
   curr = curr->next;

    }
    return;
}
```

MAIN:

```
int main()
{


    node* head = load_ll(head,"utakmice.txt");
    print_matches(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Printf-s from 'Loader function' show that the list is being correctly populated, nonetheless i am still getting 'Segmentation fault' trying to call 'print_matches' function. I'm suspicious about problem having something to do with the scope when returning from a 'Loader function'. But i have no clue how to move on.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the `load_ll` function *returning?*

Comment: Also, you don't actually create a *linked list*... All you do is create a set if independent `node` structures. The assignment `curr = curr->next` doesn't do what you apparently think it does.

Comment: You allocate `curr`, but once you do that I don't see where you ever put it into the list. ???

Comment: You don't check to see if head is NULL, you allocate curr, then you simply allocate another node, but you never link anything together.

Comment: What value do you expect to be in `head` when you use it like this: `node* head = load_ll(head,"utakmice.txt");` ?

Comment: Your function is supposed to return some new `head` value.

Comment: Do something like `prev = null; while <more data> { <allocate node> if (prev == null) head = newnode; else prev->next = newnode; ...} return head`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 1.Thank you. I edited post as it should be. Im returning the 'head node'. 2.In each iteration I am allocating space for curr node and moving it to the next node in the list witch is NULL at the end of iteration? I can't see what your pointing me at?(**The assignment curr = curr->next doesn't do what you apparently think it does. **)

Comment: @BobJarvis I thought that by allocating space and assigning values(parsed by strtok) ,then moving to the next node  im already creating nodes in the list? Then by returning head node , i get full list?

Comment: @Gerhardh  i expect same head (list) just populated.

Comment: But `head` is not initialized.

Comment: `load_ll(node* head` and you just `return` the same `head`. There is no head. It is just an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @Gerhardh Soo i must allocate head in main , then pass it ? Is that the point :D ?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk Soo i must allocate head in main , then pass it ? Is that the point :D ?

Comment: If you have `curr->next = NULL` and later do `curr = curr->next` that's equivalent to `curr = NULL`.

Comment: As you do `curr=head;` you assign an unitialized value. Dereferencing it would be undefined behaviour. But a few lines later you do `curr=malloc...` anyway which means you don't need parameter `head` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pass a head pointer to `load_ll` because it should create a list and return a pointer to the head of the created list.  Also, your current version of `load_ll` does not link the allocated list nodes together.

Here is a version of `load_ll` without the `head` parameter:

```
node* load_ll(char* file_name){
    FILE* fp;
    node *head = NULL;
    node* tail = NULL;
    node* curr;

    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Greska pri otvaranju fajla.");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buff[100];
    char* tok;

    while(fgets(&buff,100,fp) != NULL){

        curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(curr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error creating a node.");
            exit(1);
        }

        tok = strtok(buff,",");
        strcpy(curr->host,tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL,",");
        strcpy(curr->guest,tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL,",");
        curr->nrgh = atoi(tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL,",");
        curr->nrgg = atoi(tok);

        curr->next = NULL;

        printf("%s\n",curr->host);
        printf("%s\n",curr->guest);
        printf("%d\n",curr->nrgh);
        printf("%d\n",curr->nrgg);

        if(tail != NULL)
            tail->next = curr;
        else
            head = curr;
        tail = curr;
    }

    return head;
}
```

One possible use for adding a `head` parameter to the function would be to append the new entries to an existing list.  That could be done by modifying the start of the above function as follows:

```
node* load_ll(node* head, char* file_name){
    FILE* fp;
    node* tail = head;
    node* curr;

    if(tail != NULL){
        // find tail of list
        while(tail->next != NULL)
            tail = tail->next;
    }

    /* remainder of function as before */

    return head;
}
```

To create a fresh list, call it as:

```
head = load_ll(NULL, file_name);
```

To append to an existing list, call it as:

```
head = load_ll(head, file_name);
```

Since `head` is not expected to change when appending to an existing list, you could omit the assignment to `head` in that case.

You could use the same call for creating a new list or appending to an existing list as follows:

Create a new list:

```
head = NULL;
head = load_ll(head, file_name);
```

Append to an existing list:

```
head = load_ll(head, file_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer! This solves my problem. Ill study it a little bit more to break misconceptions that were in my head. :)

Answer (score 1):

You populate a new node, but don't link it to "curr"

```
while(fgets(&buff,100,fp) != NULL){

  // create a new node
  node *newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  if(newNode == NULL)
  {
     printf("Error creating a node.");
     exit(1);
  }

  tok = strtok(buff,",");       // set the data accordinly
  strcpy(newNode->host,tok);
  tok = strtok(NULL,",");
  strcpy(newNode->guest,tok);
  tok = strtok(NULL,",");
  newNode->nrgh = atoi(tok);
  tok = strtok(NULL,",");
  newNode->nrgg = atoi(tok);
  newNode->next = NULL        // .. with no successor (yet)

  // and add it to the list
  if (curr != NULL)
     curr->next = newNode;     // the new node will be the last in the list,
                               // or use it as head if it's the first element
  curr=newNode;                // next node will be attached to this one

  printf("%s\n",curr->host);
  printf("%s\n",curr->guest);
  printf("%d\n",curr->nrgh);
  printf("%d\n",curr->nrgg);
}
```

you may also save the first element, for returning it as list's head, not it's tail. And you may want to set curr to NULL before you enter the loop, curr is undefined in your code, accessing it will most probably cause a segfault

Comment: Still getting 'Segmentation fault' for trying to traverse list. I think that problem lies in segment permisions 
```
    while(curr->next != NULL){
        printf("%s\t%d\n%s\t%d\n",curr->host,curr->nrgh,curr->guest,curr->nrgg);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
``` See what i am pointing at? This results in seg_f even in a same function?

Comment: Also, process goes like this

1. Pass head of the list to function 
2. Assign curr = head (for saving head to return as first)
3. (With your code in mind) Creating newNode
4. Linking it 
5. When everything is done RETURNING HEAD(first node)

Still ... Segmentation fault.

Comment: @brapej the segfault is probably because you pass uninitialized pointer and in this version it is dereferenced: `curr->next = newNode;` which may crash

Comment: @brapej one of the first things a developer should learn is how to use a debugger. e.g. in this case, you will be shown exactly where the program crashes.